# Google Chrome - How do I hide the "Incognito + icon" on the toolbar right next to the extensions?

Tags: google-chrome

Title.

I recently "upgraded" (and deeply regretted doing so, like every time I "upgrade" a browser) and now I have this big "INCOGNITO" and icon label on the right of the extensions toolbar.

Please tell me there's a way to remove it.

Nothing in settings and I have found nothing in chrome://flags/ either

Comment: It's not possible.